# netstat with --inet option does not display listening tcp por

Tags: linux, networking, ip, netstat

Can someone please explain why the output of the command are different?

```
user@geeko:~> netstat -ln | grep 9876
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9876          :::*                    LISTEN
```

and

```
user@geeko:~> netstat -ln --inet | grep 9876
user@geeko:~>
```

Evidently it is because foreign address of the 127.0.0.1 is  `:::*` and `--inet` option shows only ports with `0.0.0.0:*` I suppose the `:::*` is ip6 format. But why `--inet|--ip` option shows only ip4 ports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you `man netstat`? It's pretty clear that `--inet` specifies tcp version 4 addresses. From the man page:

```
address_family_options:

   [-4|--inet]  [-6|--inet6]  ...
```

...So if you want IPv6, you need to add the `--inet6` or `-6` options. Or leave off `--inet` entirely, as you have seen.

Comment: Of course I did but here is my `man netstat` :   --protocol=family , -A
       Specifies the address families (perhaps better described as low level protocols) for which connections are to be shown.  family is a comma (',') separated list of address
       family keywords like inet, unix, ipx, ax25, netrom, and ddp.  This has the same effect as using the --inet, --unix (-x), --ipx, --ax25, --netrom, and --ddp options.
The address family inet includes raw, udp and tcp protocol sockets.

Comment: Your `man netstat` is the same as my `man netstat`, and in mine it's pretty clear that `--inet` is for IPv4, and `--inet6` is for IPv6. That's what I'd expect, anyway. Although I have to admit your first output is confusing because it shows "tcp" and not "tcp6". What OS version and netstat version are you using (`netstat --version`)?

Comment: It is netstat 1.42 and openSUSE Linux 13.2. I don't think our `man netstat` are the same as I have no notion of ` --inet6` in mine. Moreoever `-4` and `-6`  are invalid options but `--inet6` works.

Comment: Ahh... yes I was looking at man page for netstat from "net-tools 2.10-alpha" (note it no longer displays netstat's version alone, which the 1.42 version did). The man pages look incomplete; there's a little more description in the 2.10-alpha version but even then it's not as explicit as it could be. And there's the issue of the peculiar output. All in all, it's a little mysterious.

Comment: (as I compare the output of the old netstat with the newer, I see various tweaks in the latter. Not only is netstat deprecated, but I think 1.42 was not ready for IPv6 prime-time)